# blob data partially inserted in database

Tags: java, oracle, blob

When I insert `blob` data into Oracle database, it is partially inserted. Iam using the following code for insertion.

```
oracle.sql.BLOB newBlob =oracle.sql.BLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
newBlob.putBytes(1, str.getBytes());
ps.setBlob(1, newBlob);
```

I checked whether the data got inserted or not by querying the data and converting it into **jpeg** image, sometimes I am getting partial image. Rest of the image is grey.  Most of the time I am getting full image perfectly. What may the reason for this partial insertion?

Comment: What is `str`? How are you extracting it? I'm not sure if it's clear whether the problem is in the insertion, storage, retrieval or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the bytes of a string in the BLOB, using the default encoding. This is wrong in at least one of the following ways:

- if you're storing character data, use a CLOB
- if you're storing binary data, don't put it into a string.

Since you then say that you're dealing with a JPEG, I'd say that the string conversion is where you're having a problem. Trying to store a bunch of bytes in a Java String (which deals with characters) and then converting it back to bytes is just a bad idea. Use a `byte[]`.

Comment: `str` might be an input **stream**, not string :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - except that `java.io.InputStream` doesn't have a `getBytes()` method. And the OP's symptoms sound exactly like what would happen when using a string to hold bytes.